# Rails Radio button is only allowing me to select only first option and not the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What would be the cause of me only being able to select the first radio button, but not the second. Here is what my form looks like.
`

```
              <%= form_for [@item, Calendar.new] do |f| %>
                <div class="row">


                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <%= f.text_field :start_date, readonly: true, value: Date.today, class: "form-control datepicker" %>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <%= f.text_field :end_date, readonly: true, value: Date.today, class: "form-control datepicker" %>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
                            <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :status, Calendar.statuses, :first, :first, checked: Calendar.statuses.first do |b| 
                                b.radio_button + b.label {b.text.split("_").join("").capitalize}
                             end %>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row new-pricing">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                                    <%= f.text_field :item_price, class: "form-control", value: @item.item_price, required: true %>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <p style="margin-top: 10px"> Per Day </p>
                        </div>


                    </div>

                    <div class="no-pricing hide">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <%= f.button "Save", type: :submit, class: "btn btn-success" %>
                    </div>
            <% end %>`
```

Here is what the html looks like when I click on the "Not available" button. The checked always remains on the first value input button.
[The html in the inspection window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uZau.png)
 How can I go about fixing this. Sorry if this was an easy question.

Comment: "Rails Radio button is only allowing me to select one option and not the other" should instead be "Rails Radio button is only allowing me to select first option and not the others"

Comment: try without data-toggle="buttons-radio"

Comment: Adcosta, you're a miracle worker. So simple